# Comparing 2 dates for restricting user to select future date?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, date, uidatepicker

I am struck with an issue, please see the issue below and help to solve.

I have a datepicker in which I am showing (date, month, year), when user selects of previous date e.g 5th Nov, 2011 the label should get updated and show the selected date & if the user selects the future date beyond the current date it should show an alert to select "current or previous date".

Below is the code which I couldn't achieve the condition.

```
NSDate *post = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:post];

NSDate *dates = [datepick date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
NSString *datetime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dates];

if (datetime > theDate) 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please select current date or past date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else if(datetime <= theDate)
{
    date_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    date.text = datetime;
    [date_array addObject:datetime];
}
[dateFormat release];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Please help ASAP.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare `NSDate`s with -[NSDate compare:]. So try this:

```
if ([dates compare:post] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Healthcare" message:@"Please select current date or past date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` properties of your `UIDatePicker` instance, and the user will have no choice, but to choose date from within those bounds :)